# Clearcase application impact with MS patch

Tags: windows, security, clearcase

Could you please confirm we have no impact on the clearcase application for the below mentioned Microsoft patches. environment --> Win 2003 Enterprise SP2

```
Security    Risk       Description                              KB Number
Bulletin    

MS14-012
Critical    Cumulative Security Update for Internet Explorer    KB2925418

MS14-013
Critical    Vulnerability in Microsoft DirectShow Could Allow Remote Code Execution KB2929961

MS14-014
Important   Vulnerability in Silverlight Could Allow Security Feature Bypass    KB2932677

MS14-015
Important   Vulnerabilities in Windows Kernel-Mode Driver Could Allow Elevation of Privilege    KB2930275

MS14-016
Important   Vulnerability in Security Account Manager Remote SAMR Protocol Could Allow Security Feature Bypass  KB2934418
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No confirmation yet, but I don't see any warning reported by ibm.com about those patches.

There are only mentioned as to be applied in "[Content Released in Patches for Windows (English) - March 2014 Security Bulletins](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/a1a33778-88b7-452a-9133-c955812f8910/entry/content_released_in_patches_for_windows_english_march_2014_security_bulletins?lang=en)".
As such, their impact should be non-existent for a current ClearCase installation.